# DrawImage on mouseHover after MouseMove

Tags: c#, picturebox, mousemove, mousehover

I have a litle problem doing something I want.
What I want is quite simple.
I'm making a game tower defence for school.
When I clicked on a tower to place I want to see the tower when moving over my picturebox where everything happens in. This is no problem when I move it does what I want. But when I stop moving my Mouse I want the image stay on the position where it last was ( MouseHover).
But i don't get the mousehover event to do what I want. When I stop moving my mouse the image disapears and nothing is shown in my picturebox.

This is what i currently have for my MouseMove & MouseHover:
Note: I have already tried to use the MousePosition in the mousehover event but this doesn't work either. I hope someone can help me out on this ?

```
private void picGameArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        if (myGameLogic.tmpTower != null)
        {
            Xpos = e.X;
            YPos = e.Y;
            Graphics paper;
            paper = picGameArea.CreateGraphics();
            paper.DrawImage(myGameLogic.tmpTower.myImage, e.X - 25, e.Y -25, 50, 50);
            paper.DrawEllipse(myPen, e.X - myGameLogic.tmpTower.Range, e.Y - myGameLogic.tmpTower.Range , myGameLogic.tmpTower.Range * 2, myGameLogic.tmpTower.Range * 2);
            picGameArea.Invalidate();

        }
    }

    private void picGameArea_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics paper;
        paper = picGameArea.CreateGraphics();
        if (myGameLogic.tmpTower != null)
        {

            paper.DrawImage(myGameLogic.tmpTower.myImage, Xpos - 25, YPos - 25, 50, 50);
        }
        picGameArea.Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The image disappears because your next `Paint` event will redraw `picGameArea` and inside that event nothing will redraw your image of `tmpTower`.

You have 2 options:

- move `tmpTower` drawing inside `Paint` event.
- enable *polling* to redraw what is drawn *on top* by using timer.

There are mistakes in your code:

- `CreateGraphics` required disposing, put it inside `using` or call `paper.Dispose()`;
- there is no need to handle `MouseHover` at all, this event is used for something like showing `ToolTip`, it only triggers *once* if mouse is inside control for *some time*.
- calling `Invalidate` event will queue paint (it's like asking *please, redraw my control some time later, when you have time*), instead use `Refresh` **before** painting (and remove `Invalidate`).

Last one actually will fix your issue too...